# Hibernation during WIndows 7 update results in failure to wake

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, hibernate

Is there a setting on Windows 7 that will prevent hibernation while Windows Update is awaiting a reboot to complete installation of an update?

The repeatable scenario behind this is:

- Windows Update downloads and commences installation of an update in
  the background
- No prompt is given for the user to reboot to complete installation of the update
- The user doesn't notice that an update has occurred and hibernates
  the PC
- On attempting to awaken, the PC just sits with a black screen, never
  reaching a user prompt, never giving a message.
- The PC is hard rebooted - Holding the power button to crash it off
- Reboot normally
- On login the message "Updates failed to install" appears

The PCs (more than one) have the latest BIOS and both OS and applications are up to date - at least as far as the current installation.

If hibernation could be stopped when and only when an update reboot is required, the user wouldn't moan about losing work.

Comment: schedule the updates to a time when the computer is powered on/in use therefore avoiding hibernation?